# Django: Joining a group Works, But I cant leave A group

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have added the join group functionality, and it works fine. Now, However, Im trying to add the leave group functionality, which seems like it would be similar, but it isn't working, and not throwing me an error either. here is the code for both join and leave group. it should be noted that there is  a M2M relationship between User and Group.

1. (urls.py):

   ```
   from . import views
   from django.urls import path


   app_name = 'groups'

   urlpatterns = [
       path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
       path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
       path('<int:group_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
       path('<int:group_id>/join/', views.join, name='join'),
       path('<int:group_id>/leave/', views.join, name='leave'),

   ]
   ```
2. (views.py):

   ```
   def join(request, group_id):
       group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
       if request.method == 'POST':
           group.members.add(request.user)
           group.save()
           return redirect('/groups/' + str(group_id) )
       else:
           return render(request, '/groups/detail.html', {'group': group})

   def leave(request, group_id):
       group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)

       if request.method == 'POST':
               if request.user in group.members.all:
                   group.members.remove(request.user)
                   group.save()
                   return redirect('home')
       else:
           return render(request, '/groups/index.html')
   ```
3. groups/detail.html

   ```
   {% extends "base.html" %}

   {% block content %}

   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-4">
     <h1>{{group.name}}</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
     <p>{{group.description}}</p>
   </div>


   {% if user in group.members.all %}
   <div class="col-2">
     <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('leave').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Leave {{product.members.count}}</button></a>
   </div>
   {% else %}
     <div class="col-2">
       <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('join').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Join {{product.members.count}}</button></a>
     </div>
   {% endif %}

   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
     <img src="{{group.image.url}}" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
       <div class="row bootstrap snippets">
         <div class="col-md-3 container-widget">
             <div class="panel panel-info panel-widget">
              <div class="panel-title text-center">
                Group Members
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for member in group.members.all %}
                  <ul class="basic-list image-list">
                    <li><b>{{member.username}}</li>
                  </ul>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>



     <form method ='POST' id= 'leave' action="{% url 'groups:leave' group.id %}" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" >
    </form>


    <form method ='POST' id= 'join' action="{% url 'groups:join' group.id %}" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" >
    </form>



   {% endblock %}
   ```

   enter code here

Answer (score 0):

`group.members.all` is a method, you need to call it.

But don't do this; it unnecessarily queries all the members from the database. You could possibly use `exists()`, but actually there is no reason to check at all; `remove()` is a no-op if the item is not present. Just call it.

Also, you don't need to all `.save()` after modifying a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I am using the remove method, but still no result

Comment: I also tried iterating through group.members, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You have `views.join` written twice, the second should be `views.leave`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your leave function view is that you omitted the parenthesis to the  if statement eg. if request.user in group.members.all(): so i figured that when you add the parenthesis it should work.

```
def leave(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=group_id)
        if request.user in group.members.all():
            group.members.remove(request.user)
            group.save()
            return redirect('home')
            return HttpResponse("You have been removed successfully " + str(user.username))
            
    else:
        return render(request, '/groups/index.html')
```

I think it might be better to rename your group model in other to avoid naming conflict with the django Group model. as your model inherit from the Django model, I will suppose you do something like this:

```
class GroupExtend(models.Model):
     ...then your other fields  etc.
```